# Space between words - one line only

Tags: spacing, octavo

I would like to change the inter-words space in ONE LINE ONLY. I do not want any global changes. I saw several discussions but nothing worked, maybe just due to me not understanding the answers. Please see my MWE. I want to shrink the second line. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[foolscap, 10pt]{octavo}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[
twoside=true,
paperwidth=115mm, paperheight=195mm,
layoutsize={115mm, 195mm},
%layoutoffset={5mm, 10mm},
%textheight=15.5cm,
textwidth=8.5cm,
%outer=1.5cm,
left=1cm,
right=1.5cm,
top=1.7cm,
bottom=2.2cm
    ]
    {geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}%%% 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{layout}
%MULTIPLE COLUMNS
\usepackage{paracol}
\twosided
\footnotelayout{m}
\columnsep=0.1\textwidth
\columnratio{0.65}



\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
%\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
%\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}

\begin{document}
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{30pt}
 {\centering\footnotesize 
%Impaginazione \ dell'autore \\ Nel mese di Nissan    5783 \\ Aprile \ \  2023 \\
%Impaginazione \ dell'autore \\ Nissan 5783, Aprile  2023 \\
Impaginazione \ dell'autore \\ Nel mese di Nissan  5783 \\ Aprile 2023 \\
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\spaceskip` for spacing between words.

Comment: I tried ``` {\spaceskip 2pt plus 1pt minus 7pt
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}``` but it has no effect... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also tried to squeeze the text in a box : \makebox[2cm]{Nel mese di Nissan  5783} But nothing changes.

Comment: I ended just giving feedback to your question in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the space between words via `\spaceskip`. Similarly, you can modify the space between sentences via `\xspaceskip`. I demonstrate usage of `\spaceskip` in my minimum working example below.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\def\pangram{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{stix2}
\begin{document}
I will first find the default interword spacing for this font:
\begin{itemize}
\item
fontdimen2 (default interword space) = \the\fontdimen2\font
\item
fontdimen3 (default interword space stretch) = \the\fontdimen3\font
\item
fontdimen4 (default interword space shrink) = \the\fontdimen4\font
\end{itemize}
Thus, using 10pt=1em, the default interword spacing for \fontname\font{} is 0.2345em plus 0.1167em minus 0.078em.
Using units of em here ensures that the interword spacing scales with the font size.
\par
\bigskip
\large
I increase the font size so that the interword spacing is more clear.
\par
\textbf{Default interword spacing:}
\par
\pangram
\par
\textbf{Moreinterword spacing:}
\par
{%
    \setlength{\spaceskip}{0.6em plus 0.30em minus 0.2em}%
    \pangram{}
}
\par
\textbf{Less interword spacing:}
\par
{%
    \setlength{\spaceskip}{0.1em plus 0.05em minus 0.0667em}%
    \pangram{}
}
\par
\textbf{Back to Default interword spacing:}
\par
\pangram
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot say I understood completely your steps but it worked! Also: I did not use the stix2 package. Any special reason to use it? Thanks